# Multiple UPDATE or DELETE + INSERT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, insert

Which of those operations should perform faster in MySQL? Presume I have 999 values to change:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN(100, ..., 999);
INSERT INTO example VALUES (100, 'Peter'), (...), (999, 'Sam');
```

OR

```
UPDATE table_name SET name='Peter' 
WHERE person_id=100; ...; UPDATE table_name SET name='Sam' WHERE person_id=999;
```

Comment: What about [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have only 900 row values to change then first option will perform fast. Because you  will have only two queries to run. But if you go for second option then you will have almost 900 queries to run that will definitely slow. And more better idea to do same would be

```
TRUNCATE FROM table;
INSERT INTO example VALUES (100, 'Peter'), (...), (999, 'Sam');
```

because truncate works faster than delete.

Comment: Scenario says 999 values to change, so the table can have thousands or records, but user is only interested in changing 999 of all.

Comment: Himanshu is right, I could have millions of records with idea to update only 999 records.

Comment: In such case you need to go with option two because bulk insert has some limitations with huge amount of data as my previous answer was for only for 999 rows.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, those two operations (DELETE/INSERT vs UPDATE) could have significantly *different* results, based on the current state of the table... Does row with id=999 exist? Are there foreign key constraints that reference this table? Are there any triggers defined on the table?

If the specification is to update rows in a table, I would issue an UPDATE statement, rather than issuing a DELETE and INSERT.

There are factors beyond speed to consider.

But fastest would likely be:

```
 UPDATE example t
    SET t.name  
        = CASE t.id
            WHEN 100 THEN 'Peter'
            WHEN ...
            WHEN 999 THEN 'Sam'
            ELSE t.name
          END
   WHERE t.id IN (100,...999)
```